# How do I use R code to solve for probability of normal distributions?

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I don't understand which R code I am supposed to be using to figure these problems out. I brief explanation of what the code is doing would be amazing. The problems below are two different applications I'm expected to understand and I don't get either. Thank you!

```
Problem 1. Let Z~N(0,1) For each of the following, find c such that the equation is true. 

a) P(Z<c) = 0.8413 
b) P(0<Z<c) = 0.3051 
c) P(-c<Z<c) = 0.8664 

Problem 2. X~N(3,4) compute 
a) P(X>3) 
b) P(1<X<8) 
c) P(-1.5<X<1)
```

Comment: Problems 1 corresponds to the function `qnorm` and problem 2 corresponds to `pnrom`. But this obviously is some sort of basic statistical homework assignment. If you don't understand the statistics, ask on [stats.se], if you don't understand the R functions, first read the `?pnorm` help page. If you still have questions, as a much more specific question. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site for programming questions; not stats tutoring.

Comment: To explain a bit. The first problem asks you to find "quantiles", that is, values that "cut off" certain chunks from under the normal curve. Here you have to find the interval that corresponds to the given probability. The second problem asks the reversed question. Here you are asked to calculate the probability of a given interval under a normal distribution with mean 3, variance 4. The comment above points to the relevant functions and help-pages.

Comment: ?pnorm ... that page has all the functions required.

Comment: While you can ask about homework (or routine bookwork more generally) here, it is treated differently. Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), change your question as necessary, including explaining what you've tried in order to solve your problem and explaining precisely where your difficulties lie.