# R code to solve for probability of normal distributions?

Tags: r, self-study, normal-distribution

I don't understand which R code I am supposed to be using to figure these problems out. I brief explanation of what the code is doing would be amazing. The problems below are two different applications I'm expected to understand and I don't get either. Thank you!

```
Problem 1. Let Z~N(0,1) For each of the following, find c such that the equation is true. 

a) P(Z<c) = 0.8413 
b) P(0<Z<c) = 0.3051 
c) P(-c<Z<c) = 0.8664 

Problem 2. X~N(3,4) compute 
a) P(X>3) 
b) P(1<X<8) 
c) P(-1.5<X<1)
```

Comment: Try `?pnorm`and `?qnorm`

Comment: I tried. I unfortunately don't understand the functionality of them. That's what I was hoping could be explained. If I could see a few examples of them in use I think that would really help.

Comment: The `R` commands @Henry recommended bring up a help page that includes such examples *in executable form* so you can reproduce them and modify them yourself.  The plots might be especially instructive.

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html

Comment: I've flagged the other copy of your question [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117590/how-do-i-use-r-code-to-solve-for-probability-of-normal-distributions?noredirect=1) as a duplicate of this one, but please note the comments there apply to this one. Please read my comments there (particularly relating to this being `self-study`) as if they were made here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question so much about how to use R as trying to understand the distribution & quantile functions (which could be implemented in any language). This could stay open, IMO.

Comment: I agree that the R help pages for these functions are not very clear or helpful.  But this question seems off topic here and would be better on an R list.

Answer (score 3):

As examples,

```
> pnorm(0.1234, mean=5, sd=6)
[1] 0.2081759
> qnorm(0.1234, mean=5, sd=6)
[1] -1.948942
```

indicate that for a random variable $X$ with a normal distribution of mean $5$ and standard deviation $6$:

$$\Pr(X \le 0.1234) = 0.2081759$$ and 
$$\Pr(X \le -1.948942) = 0.1234.$$

By adjusting these and using subtraction, you should be able to solve your questions.  For question $1$(c) you will need to use the symmetry of a normal distribution about its mean.

Answer (score 0):

2.b)
I don't know exactly which function can do that but you can try it:

```
P(1<X<8)= 1-pnorm(1,3,2)-pnorm(8,3,2,lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you expand this by giving some explanation as to why it works?

Answer (score 0):

Problem1:
a. > qnorm(0.8413, 0,1)
[1] 0.9998151

b.> qnorm((0.5+0.3051), 0,1)
[1] 0.8599801

c. > qnorm((0.8664/2+0.5),0,1)
[1] 1.500056

Problem2
a.> pnorm(3, 3, 4, lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.5

b.> pnorm(8, 3,4)-pnorm(1,3,4)
[1] 0.5858127

c. > pnorm(1, 3,4)-pnorm(-1.5,3,4)
[1] 0.178243

Comment: It actually is confusing to post answers with more significant digits than the problem.  The intended answer to (1a), for instance, is $1$.  Your use of software to obtain these numbers is obscuring the basic concepts the exercises are aimed at elucidating.